# Calculating the root of a quadratic equation. C++

Tags: c++, equation, quadratic

I want to calculate the root of a quadratic equation `ax2 + bx + c = 0`. I think my algorithm is correct, but I am new to functions and I think my mistake is with calling them. Could you help me? Thank you in advance. Here is the code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
const double EPS = 1.0e-14;
int quadraticEquation(int& a,int& b, int& c)

{
    if(abs(a) < EPS)
    {
        if(abs(b) < EPS)
        {
            cout << "No solution" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            double x = - c /b ;
            cout << "One root: " << x << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        double delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;
        if(delta < 0)
        {
            cout << "No solution:\n" ;
        }
        else
        {
            double square_delta = sqrt(delta);
            double root_1 = (-b + square_delta) / (2 * a);
            double root_2 = (-b - square_delta) / (2 * a);
            cout << "x1 = " << root_1 << endl;
            cout << "x2 = " << root_2 << endl;
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    cout << "The solution is: " << quadraticEquation(int a,int b,int c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your actual problem?

Comment: As you implicitly note in your code, a quadratic equation generally has *two* solutions, and they're usually not integers.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Well, he's not returning anything anyway. Just printing both roots from inside the function. But he's also printing the undefined return value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Define the function as:

```
int quadraticEquation(int a,int b, int c)
```

Without & signs to pass the parameters by value instead of by reference (althought as juanchopanza states on a comment it is not extrictly required).

And call it as:

```
cout << "The solution is: " << quadraticEquation( a, b, c);
```

Without int because in function calls you must not provide the type of the parameter.

Comment: The first part of the answer is both unnecessary and wrong (although it does make sense to pass integers by value in this case.)

Comment: Edited my answer. I hope that it is more accurate now.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
cout << "The solution is: " << quadraticEquation(a, b, c); // no types in calling a function
```

Comment: Wow, what stupid mistake have I done. Really thanks erenon!

Answer (score 2):

It is not really the question asked, and erenon and Paco Abato did answer the C++ problem.

But there are still some improvement to your algorythm :

- abs(a) < EPS and abs(b) < EPS - if abc(c) < EPS every x is solution
- if delta < 0 should be `if delta <= (-EPS)`
- you forgot `if abs(delta) < EPS)` one double solution : `double x = - b / a;`